# Field name collision (_id) when doing unwind

Tags: c#, mongodb, subquery, aggregation

I have mongo collection where the documents look like this:

```
{ 
  _id: "384iojweiu83ur8233uui",
  name: "Jack",
  friends: [
    { 
      _id: "384798237498234",
      name: "Alfred"
    },
    { 
      _id: "384798234749829",
      name: "Deborah"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to retrieve a person given its `_id` and only a friend given the friend `_id`. Something like this:

```
{ 
  _id: "384iojweiu83ur8233uui",
  name: "Jack",
  friend_id: "384798237498234",
  friend_name: "Alfred"  
}
```

I was trying to do so through the `unwind` method in the c# mongo driver, however I'm stuck at this point.

```
var people = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind<Person, PersonWithFriend>(_ => _.friends } )
    .Match( _ => _.Id == new ObjectId("5b646004b5728100042dd358"))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [positional operator `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#examples) to return only the first matching element of the array:

```
db.users.find(
    { "friends._id": "384798237498234" },
    { "name": 1, "friends.$": 1 }
);
```

Or, if you need to match multiple conditions on a `friends` subdocument, you can use `$elemMatch`:

```
db.users.find(
    { "friends":  { 
        "$elemMatch": { "id": "384798237498234",  "somethingElse": "..." }
    }},
    { "name": 1, "friends.$": 1 }
);
```

Which would generate a result with a `friends` array with a single element:

```
{ 
    _id: "384iojweiu83ur8233uui",
    name: "Jack",
    friends: [{
        id: "384798237498234",
        name: "Alfred"  
    }]
}
```

If you really need to have the friend's `id` and `name` in the root of the result object, then you can do the same thing using the aggregation framework and add an unwind step at the end.

In C# it should be something like this:

```
users
    .Find(user => user.friends.Any(friend => friend.id == "384798237498234"))
    .Project(projection)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Sorry @Danziger I'm asking how to do it in C# MongoDB Driver Pipeline, not pure mongodb js. But thank you. I'll try with the Bson document query approach.